# RecyclerView Slide New Item In At Top

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-recyclerview

I recently set up my RecyclerView and want to slide in all new items that are added. Specifically, I have a comment screen and every time a new comment is added, I want it to slide in from the left with an animation effect.

Note that I add all new items to my `mCommentArrayList` at `index 0` so that they appear at the top of the view.

I have read about using third-party libraries, but from what I understand that is not necessary. Here is my code:

Where I first call to Firebase to find data to populate the RecyclerView:

```
    mUpdateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            setImage(dataSnapshot);
            setQuestion(dataSnapshot);
            createInitialCommentIDArray(dataSnapshot);
            mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll = (int) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).getChildrenCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll; i++) {
                String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("COMMENT").getValue();
                Log.v("COMMENT_ID", "The comment ID is " + commentID);
                String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("USER_ID").getValue();
                Log.v("USER_ID", "The user ID is " + userID);
                mCommentArrayList.add(0, new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Subsequent Calls to Firebase on Data Change:

```
   @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mUpdateComments = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            for (DataSnapshot x : dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).getChildren()) {
                Log.v("DATA_SNAPSHOT", x.toString());
                if (mCommentIDArrayList.contains(x.getKey())) {
                    Log.v("Comment_Already_Added", x.getKey());
                } else {
                    Log.v("Child_Added_Called", "Child Added Called");
                    mCommentIDArrayList.add(x.getKey());
                    String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(x.getKey()).child("COMMENT").getValue();
                    Log.v("New_Comment", "The new comment is " + commentID);
                    String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(x.getKey()).child("USER_ID").getValue();
                    Log.v("New_User_ID", "The new userID is " + userID);
                    mCommentArrayList.add(0, new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
                    mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Comments> mDataSet;


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        protected ImageView userAvatar;
        protected TextView userID;
        protected TextView userComment;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            userAvatar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            userID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_ID);
            userComment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_comment_textview);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Comments> myDataset) {
        mDataSet = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.individual_comment, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)

    //The OutOfBoundsException is pointing here
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Comments comment = mDataSet.get(position);
        holder.userComment.setText(comment.getUserComment());
        holder.userID.setText("User " + position);
    }


    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here? You've already added them to the top of the list?

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to incorporate a slide in animation, I understand there is some code to be added to 'onBindViewHolder()' but want to confirm